# Background sync in iOS7

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios7, background-process

We have to develop an app which will support data sync operations at some time interval, whether the app is in foreground or in background.

I want to know that in iOS7…

- is it possible to sync data (i.e. call web services) while the app is in background?
- can we access SQLite data base file/can we do DB operations while the app is in background?
- can we run timers in background?
- can we show alerts about some updates while the app is in background?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I absolutely agree with Wain - you should reconsider your approach. There usually is no special reason for an app to be synced while in the background. If user has to know something - send push notification. If one chooses to open the app - app can sync (and is no longer in background). If one chooses not to open the app - then there is no immediate reason for syncing. It seems like you are trying to update your app periodically polling the server - don't. You can always send an empty push notification (user doesn't see a thing) to initiate a sync sequence.

Comment: Polling might actually be the way to go, for 2 reasons.  1: If your users need access to updated data while offline, and don't want to have to manually sync or use the app before they go offline.  2: Silent push notifications have seriously flaws and are mostly unusable (i.e.-if user "force quits" your app, pushes stop working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, it is.
2. Yes, you can.
3. Sometimes, but you shouldn't.
4. Yes, you can.

Go and research iOS 7 background operations. Talk of using timers and background operations `at some time interval` indicate you're approaching the problem in a way that won't work. While the answer to most of your questions is yes, your approach is probably no...

Start with [application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3aperformFetchWithCompletionHandler%3a).

Comment: Thanks wain. Can you please elaborate the approaches for the same? Actually, I came to know that we can only upload/download the file while the app is in background but not the data. Our requirement is to access the DB and send the data from db to server and get the latest data from server to our db, while the app is in background too.

Comment: You have a limited time so you need to be efficient. Using `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:` your app can be given time in which to do these tasks (approx 30 seconds). You can't choose when it's called, iOS chooses that based (primarily) on user interaction. Research and then ask specific questions about things you don't understand.

Comment: @Wain how to sync data when app is not launched ? I came across remote push notification but it will work on only in app is in background or foreground...So do you have any idea to achieve this?

Comment: @patel kavit Did you get any way to implement your requirement? I need to do same