# Synchronize data between server and iOS application

Tags: ios, sqlite, server, synchronize

How to synchronize new data added in the database of server or middle ware to the devices installed our app?

Answer (score 0):

Typically what's done is the app makes a call to the server to refresh the data when it's opened or a refresh has been requested.

If you want the user to know they're missing out on new data, you should use push notifications to let them know the number of new updates.

Answer (score 0):

if you are supporting iOS7  and above you can do background data sync , for more info refer to similar question at [Background sync in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600955/background-sync-in-ios7)